# Apache redirect for query string

Tags: apache, redirect, nginx, administrator

I have a question about Apache redirect. Please see my scenario below.

I have an URL `sub.example.com` which need to be redirected to `www.example.com/index.php?r=something`. When I load `www.example.com/index.php?r=something` in my browser, the css file is getting loaded from `www.example.com/css/file.css`. So I couldn't write a simple redirect for `sub.example.com` to `www.example.com/index.php?r=something` since it will result 404 for css file. I fixed that issues by applying the below redirect rule and it works fine(means css file is also get loaded).

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.+/?)?(/|\.htm|\.php|\.html|/[^.]*)$ http://www.example.com/index.php?r=something [P]
```

My problem is now when I put `sub.example.com/?success=1` it should redirect to `www.example.com/index.php?r=something&success=1`. Does the above rule will satisfy this ? If not can you please help to modify the rule accordingly. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some googling, I found a solution to this. There is a QSA(Query String Append) flag that will force the rewrite engine to append a query string part of the substitution string to the existing string. So I had to add that flag into the existing Rewrite rule as given below.

```
RewriteRule ^(.+/?)?(/|\.htm|\.php|\.html|/[^.]*)$ http://www.example.com/index.php?r=something [P,QSA]
```

And voila, the issue got resolved.

Thanks,